# how to claim a jwt token based on user->id in lumen

Tags: laravel, authentication, laravel-5, lumen, jwt

I installed **lumen 5.5** and `"tymon/jwt-auth": "^1.0@dev"` as well.

I configured everything and also claiming token on email and password. 
I want to claim token based on user id and store claimed user in jwt_auth_guard. what will be best approach? please help me out.

Comment: what do you mean by claiming token based on user id? can you elaborate

Comment: I am validating user based on accountname and creadention that is actually not a password, after validation I am fetching user_id and I just want to store that user to jwt_auth_guard and generate jwt_token for that user.

Comment: I think you are looking for https://github.com/tymondesigns/jwt-auth/wiki/Creating-Tokens#creating-a-token-based-on-a-user-object

so basically you can fetch the user object and create the token for the user.

Or if you just wanted the user_id, you can use this instead https://github.com/tymondesigns/jwt-auth/wiki/Creating-Tokens#creating-a-token-based-on-anything-you-like

Comment: This worked for me. Thanks a lot.

Comment: One more thing where I have query regarding JWT. After logged in when I pass api token in url it works, but I want to pass this token in header with key_name api_token. where I have to change for that?

Comment: In simple word I want that user pass his logged in token into header not into input field and then compare it that it is valid or not. I tried following code but it's giving an exception that token is required in my custom middleware

$auth_token=$request->header('Auth-Token');
$user=$this->auth->authenticate($auth_token);